# Assigning multiple assets to multiple variables on inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there a way to assign multiple assets to multiple variables on the inspector???

My case is this, I have 5 objects, those objects have a script wich have around 1200 variables used to play SFXs. When Unity compile the script I have to manually drag and drop the SFX from the assets to the variable on the inspector, or go to the inspector, scrol to the variable, click the dot and then select the SFX file from the window.

[image]

Is there a way to speed this up?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a public List of Audio Sources which will appear in inspector. Lock the inspector by clicking look in right top.
Now select all the files from Project and drag on list. All files will be added to list. Now if you want a specific file you can find the file by its name for example:

```
AudioSource GetAudioSource(string SourceName)
{
return audioSourceList.Find(item => item.Name == SourceName);
}
```

Comment: Dont forget to hit the title of the list in inspector, while dragging

Answer (score 0):

Use the Resources.LoadAll method to access all the assets from the path parameter via scripting.  Probably put that method call in Start.  Might have to rename the files to pull the right order from the LoadAll method if they result in some alternate order.

EDIT: Here's some example code...

(NOTE: Loads from Resources/Sound/SFX folder)

For reference: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.LoadAll.html

```
public class YourClassNameGoesHere : MonoBehaviour
{
    Public AudioClip[] BA;

    void Start ()
    {
        BA = (AudioClip[]) Resources.LoadAll("Sound/SFX");
    }

}
```

Comment: Hum... I feel that your question could lead me to my answer. Let me rephrace the question: Could I do something like `Public AudioClip BA;` and then later `BA = Load("Sound/SFX");`, I mean, declare the variable and inside the code assign the asset directly?

Comment: The problem with your example is that it will load all sounds found on SFX folder into a array called BA. That's NOT what I need. What I need is assign every sound in that folder to every AudioClip variable. For example, Public AudioClip ba with BA.wav, Public AudioClip be with be.wav, and so on... I try `ac = Resources.Load("Sound/SFX/Silabas/2/AC.wav") as AudioClip;`but it didn't work, at runtime, the variable ac is empty, it doesn't have the sound AC.wav assign to it...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem. I must say, it's not perfect, in fact, it should not be used unless is absolutely necessary.

To speed up the assign you could do this:

Create a variable

```
 public AudioClip ma, me, mi, mo, mu;
```

At Start() add

```
 ma = Resources.Load("Sound/SFX/MA") as AudioClip;
 me = Resources.Load("Sound/SFX/ME") as AudioClip;
 mi = Resources.Load("Sound/SFX/MI") as AudioClip;
 mo = Resources.Load("Sound/SFX/MO") as AudioClip;
 mu = Resources.Load("Sound/SFX/MU") as AudioClip;
```

After compile the public variables will be available on the Inspector as empty variables, but, on runtime the variables will be filled with the content of the folder Resources/Sound/SFX (Assets\Resources\Sound\SFX).

Why shouldn't be use unless necessary?, first, it's a bad practice; second, it's a cheap trick that comes at a price (on mobile devices it load all the resources so will consume RAM fast). In my test, all my sound clips take as much as 169 MB. On PC it's not much of a problem, but if your target is Mobile games, this is something to take into consideration. And third, on web player, ALL resources will be streamed first.

On a side note, this cheap trick ignores the way Unity handles assets. Unity force you to assign assets manually because if the asset is not use, it will not be integrated into the build. This trick force everything to be loaded and be integrated into the final build, used or no. On the other hand, if you are assign it, you will use it... right?

The answer and example given by @Jayson Ash lead me to the right direction.